# Haskell expression evaluation?

Tags: haskell

I have the following type and function definitions:

```
data Tree a = Tree a [Tree a]
list t = list' [t]
           where list'  [] = []
                 list'  (Tree a hs:ts) = a : list' (ts ++ hs)
```

and I have this expression:

```
list (Tree (-1) [Tree 0 [ Tree 4 [], Tree 7 []],Tree 8 [Tree 5 []]])
```

Which is giving me:

```
[-1,0,8,4,7,5]
```

Problem is I can't understand why! I think my problem is that I can't understand why `list'` takes a list as an argument and at the second where expressions it uses: `(Tree a hs:ts)`, and not something like `x:xs`. I'm new at Haskell so probably this is something basic but I couldn't understand it.
Thank you and sorry for my english!

Comment: You should post the functions `list`, `list'` and `listar`.

Comment: The `listar` one was a mistake, i meant list. `list` and `list'` are there!

Comment: `(Tree a hs:ts)` is the same thing as `((Tree a hs):ts)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pattern matches can be nested. So `x:xs` is not the only way to pattern match against a non-empty list.

When you match `(Tree a hs : ts)` against a list of trees, what it does is bind the tail of the list of trees to `ts` and continue pattern matching the first tree in the list against `Tree a hs`. This will bind `a` to the key of the first element of the list of trees and `hs` to the child trees of the first tree of the list of trees.